# how do I best display matches from a large json object?

Tags: javascript, json, search

I am loading data from a json object into a table on my page. Then I allow the user to filter that data via an input and display only the matches. My method of doing this is surely not great but it does work.

Now I want to do the exact same thing with a list of airports and their codes. Problem is that the airport list is much longer and the page bogs down significantly when loading the table with data and when it searches for the user's input in the table.

Here's the information for the page that does work so you can se what Im doing.

**What can I do differently to achive the same effect I have here when I have a much larger data set to search?**

Page Displaying data: (type "american airlines" or "aa"as an example)
https://pnrbuilder.com/_popups/dataDecoder.php

json object containing airline information:
https://pnrbuilder.com/_java/airlineDecoder.js

Sript that loads data to the page and filters it based on user input:
https://pnrbuilder.com/_java/decodeData.js

---

Here's the most significant parts of my code:

```
// This function is called by a for loop on dom ready
// It basically prints data stored in a json object to a table on the page 



function fillInfo(line) {

    var table = document.getElementById('decodeTable');

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(row);

    var col1 = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(col1);
    var curCode = document.createTextNode(arlnInfo.d[line].IATA);
    col1.appendChild(curCode);

    var col2 = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(col2);
    var curArln = document.createTextNode(arlnInfo.d[line].Airline);
    col2.appendChild(curArln);

    var col3 = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(col3);
    var curPre = document.createTextNode(arlnInfo.d[line].Prefix);
    col3.appendChild(curPre);

    var col4 = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(col4);
    var curIcao = document.createTextNode(arlnInfo.d[line].ICAO);
    col4.appendChild(curIcao);

    var col5 = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(col5);
    var curCnty = document.createTextNode(arlnInfo.d[line].Country);
    col5.appendChild(curCnty);


}


// This function checks user input against data in the table 
// If a match is found whitin a row, the row containing the match is shown
// If a match is not found that row is hidden 



function filterTable(input) {

    var decodeTable = document.getElementById('decodeTable');
    var inputLength = input.length;


// THis first part makes sure that all rows of the generated table are hidden when no input is present 

    if (inputLength == 0) {            

        for (var r = 1; r < decodeTable.rows.length; r++) {

            decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "none";

        }

    } 


// This part checks just the airline codes "column" of the table when input is only one or two characters


    else if (inputLength < 3) {

        for (var r = 1; r < decodeTable.rows.length; r++) {

            var celVal = $(decodeTable.rows[r].cells[0])
                .text()
                .slice(0, inputLength)
                .toLowerCase();
            if (celVal == input) {
                decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "";
            } else {
                decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "none";
            }

        }
    }

// This part checks several "columns" of the table when input is more than two characters

    else if (inputLength > 2) {

        for (var r = 1; r < decodeTable.rows.length; r++) {

            var celVal = $(decodeTable.rows[r].cells[2])
                .text()
                .slice(0, inputLength)
                .toLowerCase();
            var celVal2 = $(decodeTable.rows[r].cells[1])
                .text();
            if (celVal == input || celVal2 == input) {
                decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "";
            } else if (celVal2.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "")
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(input) >= 0) {
                decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "";
            } else {
                decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "none";
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Couldn´t you check the input against the JSON data instead? And add a property for each object, like isVisible: true/false. When all are set, loop through the JSON array and: if (!isVisible) {...hide table row}

Comment: Im sure I could. Would that be faster? The "filter function" gets called on every keyup event for the input. Would looping through the JSON object assigning/ removing  isVisible then looping trough the JSON array again to load the visible slots to the table be that much less than what im doing now? Not rejecting it, just want to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first little optimization you could apply is not to do the entire filter on every key up, wait until the user finished typing so delay calling it for half a second:

```
var timeOut = 0;
$("#deCode").keyup(function () {
    // cancel looking, the user typed another character
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    // set a timeout, when user doesn't type another key
    // within half a second the filter will run
    var input = $("#deCode").val().toLowerCase().trim();
    timeOut=setTimeout(function(){
        filterTable(input)
    },500);
});
```

The next is comparing to your json data instead of jquery objects and converting your JSON data to lower case after creating the table so you don't have to check toLowerCase every time for every row:

```
function filterTable(input) {
    var decodeTable = document.getElementById('decodeTable');
    var inputLength = input.length;
    if (inputLength ==0) {
        for (var r = 1; r < decodeTable.rows.length; r++) {
            decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else if (inputLength <3) {
        for (var r = 0; r < arlnInfo.d.length; r++) {
            if (arlnInfo.d[r].IATA.indexOf(input)===0) {
                decodeTable.rows[r+1].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                decodeTable.rows[r+1].style.display = "none"; 
            }

        }
    }
    else if (inputLength > 2) {
        for (var r = 0; r < arlnInfo.d.length; r++) {
            if (arlnInfo.d[r].Prefix.indexOf(input)===0) {
                decodeTable.rows[r].style.display = "";
            }
            else if (arlnInfo.d[r].Airline.indexOf(input) >= 0) {
                decodeTable.rows[r + 1].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                decodeTable.rows[r + 1].style.display = "none";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Problem is with your JSON data: `"Prefix": 430` causes `arlnInfo.d[r].Prefix.slice(0, inputLength)` to throw an error because the data isn't a string but a number. If you have control over the JSON then you should convert these values to string (`"Prefix":"430"`), If you don't then convert it once and re create airlineDecoder.js using `JSON.stringify(arlnInfo);`

To convert your JSON you can copy and paste this in the chrome console (press F12) and run it (press enter). It'll log the converted JSON but you may need an IDE like netbeans to re format it:

```
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<arlnInfo.d.length;i++){
  arlnInfo.d[i].Prefix=arlnInfo.d[i].Prefix+"";
}
console.log("var arlnInfo = " + JSON.stringify(arlnInfo));
```

A last optimization you can apply is use DocumentFragment instead of directly adding every row to DOM, here we convert the JSON data to lower case so we don't have to do that for every search:

```
var decodeTable = document.getElementById('decodeTable');
function createTable() {
    var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < arlnInfo.d.length; i++) {
        fillInfo(i, df);
        arlnInfo.d[i].IATA = arlnInfo.d[i].IATA.toLowerCase()
        arlnInfo.d[i].Prefix = arlnInfo.d[i].Prefix.toLowerCase();
        arlnInfo.d[i].Airline = arlnInfo.d[i].Airline.toLowerCase();
    }
    decodeTable.appendChild(df);
}
createTable();
....
function fillInfo(line,df) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
        df.appendChild(row);
     ....
     row.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Ah,I see. So setting the isVisible to the array then loading only those would indeed be faster than looping through the table rows. And I like the delay for sure. But how do I then remove rows from the table which no longer match the input if the user backspaces or continues typing?

Comment: @eosterberg Yes, I've updated the answer, wanted to test and see if you could use the JSON data to use for the search, it works but JSON needs to be changed

Comment: I can indeed change the JSON (used an online tool to create it, sucked it made them all numbers) I had hoped to avoid changing that as the only way I know how is to do it by hand and that list is quite large. Seems I will be adding all of those quotes after all. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @DelightedD0D I'll add a conversion script in my answer

Comment: Add you are officially awesome. Thank again.

Comment: @DelightedD0D You're welcome, made some changes to the code again, I think that's about all the optimization I can squeeze out of it without changing all the code. If you want to show a maximum of about 20 rows than it's best to not even create the table in the first place and use the DocumentFragment to create and add rows that fit the search criteria (if not over a certain amount) this will save the client some memory to render your page.